# Laravel Error: Access denied for user 'db_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@admin.com limit 1)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, web

I was searching for solutions here on SO, I saw multiple questions similar to this one but I didn't find an answer that can resolve this issue. My site is live on the server, and on logging in as admin it is giving this error. Here is my .env file code:

**env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=myroyal8_laravel
DB_PASSWORD=myroyal8_laravel99!
```

Here is the SS of error.

[image: SS of Error Message]

Please guide me as I'm stuck here for a while. Any suggestions/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to access your database by other means?

Comment: @Rwd Yes, through cpanel & phpmyadmin

Comment: This should not be an issue with Laravel, try accessing your database via a command prompt or by manually entering the details in PhpMyAdmin. I doubt that there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: @RaedYakoubi you mean the login details of phpmyadmin?

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad Yes, there might be a typo. There is also a possibility that the MySQL server is not remotely accessible, in that case you have to look and find an option to allow remote access, if that option is not available i recommend you contacting your hosting provider.

Comment: @RaedYakoubi these login details were working fine a few days back. But suddenly this issue started. This site is placed on cpanel and db is accessible through the db login credentials

Comment: Oh, is this happening when you run the application locally? If so, the server (`DB_HOST`) needs to be changed to your server's address.

Comment: No, I'm not accessing it locally. The db and project files both are on server.

Comment: Do I need to change the server address from 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Try visiting your MySQL accounts page in the CPanel then check for the server address, if it is correct, look if there is something such as privileges for each account.

Comment: @RaedYakoubi thanks for the suggestion. I’ll check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct your problem:

The server is trying to connect using the myroyal8_laravel username. You have either not created a user named myroyal8_laravel in mysql or have a different password set.

Comment: Yes, what I think is that the login details are not matching with the ones that are in db

Answer (score 0):

First check your user name am password in database.

if don't work than try`php artisan cache:clear`

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database username and passwords are correct.

Also try and run these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Since it's live, you can use SSH to access the server and run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't suggest doing that, you can try loading the details directly in your `config/database.php` file like this:

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'your_database_name',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX'),
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
    ],
```